# Write Genepop friendly .txt file from a regular data frame in R

Tags: r, genetics, population

I've lost an entire day of work trying to do this operation which look very simple but apparently isn't that easy :

I have a dataframe with the first column as my population column, the other columns are loci and each row is an individual : (this is the format used by hierFstat by the way)

I would like to convert this data frame to a .txt file usable by the genepop package and I can't manage to find a solution that fit what I would like to do and it seems I'm not able to write such a function myself.

Here is my data frame :
[image]

Anyone ever had to do such an operation ? and know a way ?

Thanks for your time !

(Sorry I'm new to the forum I hope I'm clear and correct)

Comment: Not everyone (me included!) is familaiar with the genepop package.  It would help if you could describe/define the format required.  Also, providing data as an image is distinctly unhelpful: put yourself in our shoes and you will realise that we have to manually transcribe your data before we even beging to help you.  Why should we do that when you have a much more convenient method available to you: post the output from `dput()` to your question.  Oh, welcome to SO!

Comment: Please share your data using ``dput(head(dat))`` rather than as an image. We also have no idea what the format for genepop is. Please post an example output.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimum reproducible example*.

Comment: Thank you for your time and contructive comment I finaly found the problem (down below) !

Answer (score 0):

I guess `write.table()` is the function you are looking for. Just have a look at the R documentation via `?write.table`.
Should look like this:

```
write.table(df_name, file= "filename.txt", ...)
```

You could also create a csv file and later on save it as a txt file (for example via Excel). Therefore you could use `write.csv()` or `write.csv2()`. Please have a look at the corresponding R documentation, or simply google the functions.

Is there a specific reason why you want to use a function of a specific package?

Comment: Hello and thank you ! It's ok I figured it out ! I had a script using write.table and cat that would write a .txt file following the instructions given here : https://genepop.curtin.edu.au/help_input.html (second alternative)
but the problem was the NA need to be written 000000 instead of NA or 0.
thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

when figuring out the answer to your question, it's important to share a reproducible code example.

Dummy data frame example:

| Sample | LocusA | LocusB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 076331 | 145131 |
| 2 | 012076 | NA |
| 3 | 331012 | 145012 |
| 4 | NA | 131076 |

etc...

Convert data frame to genepop format:

```
#Get data from .csv (or others formats)
rawtable <- read.csv("raw_alleles.csv", header = TRUE)

#Replace NAs of all data.frame
rawtable[is.na(rawtable)] <- 000000

#select and join alleles
#you can exclude Sample number and remained just with Group1 to declare 
#the population, this not compromise the downstream analysis
haplotypes <- as.data.frame(paste("Group1_", rawtable$Sample, ","," ", rawtable$LocusA," ", rawtable$LocusB, sep = ""))

#Build the Genepop format
sink("genepop_format.txt")
cat("Title: Any information \n")
cat("LocusA \n")
cat("LocusB \n")
cat("Pop \n")
invisible(apply(haplotypes, 1,function(x) cat(x,"\n")))
sink()
```

The output file should be similar to this:

```
------------- The file starts here ---------------- 
 Title: Any Information 
 LocusA
 LocusB 
 Pop 
 Group1_1, 076331 145131
 Group1_2, 012076 000000
 Group1_3, 331012 145012
 Group1_4, 000000 145012
```